# DCOS 1.7 authentication failure with Invalid token. Reason: not enough data

Tags: mesos, mesosphere, dcos

We built dcos 1.7 cluster in aws using cloud formation template by following "launch dc/os" instructions here https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/cloud/aws/

I tried to run the following query using curl

```
curl --header " Authorization: token=xxxxx" https://{dcos-elb}/service/chronos/scheduler/jobs
```

but got

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Unauthorized</title>
<noscript><meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=/#/login"></noscript>
<script>
  (function () {
    var location = window.location;
    location.href = "/#/login?redirect=" + encodeURIComponent(location.href);
  }())
</script>
</head>
<body>
   <h1>Unauthorized</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

I obtained the token by following these instructions
https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/security/managing-authentication/#log-in-cli

i.e. in browser paste this url: https:///login?redirect_uri=urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob, login with google creds and then copy the token

adminrouter logs in master node has following lines

```
[notice] 31915#0: *8026 [lua] auth.lua:119: validate_jwt_or_exit(): Invalid token. Reason: not enough data, client: xx.xx.xx.xx, server: dcos.*, request: "GET /service/chronos/scheduler/jobs HTTP/1.1", host: "xxxxx"
```

How can I resolve this issue ?. Do I have to include any extra payload with curl query ?

Any suggestions would be much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First do,  `dcos config show`  and check the variable value for `core.dcos_url` , make sure you are hitting "HTTP"  and **NOT** "HTTPS".

To make the change, follow the below procedure,

1:) `dcos config unset core.dcos_url`

2:) `dcos config set core.dcos_url  <CLuster_URL_Only_HTTP>`

3:) Finally you can do , `dcos auth login`

4:) Step (3) will return URL, which you have to paste in Browser and get the Token and paste it on the Cli, where it's waiting for Token.

Comment: Hi, I used my mesos master ip as `dcos config set core.dcos_url http://10.198.161.42:5050`  and then `dcos auth login`  but its giving me the error as _Error while fetching [http://10.198.161.42:5050/exhibitor/]: HTTP 404: Not Found_